# Swift : Date difference

Tags: java, ios, swift, time

I couldn't find a way to write this in swift, but how can I take the date difference between now and the end of the year? I have done this in java but couldn't find a way to do the same in swift. Here's the java logic i wrote:

```
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar endOfYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        endOfYear.setTime(new Date(0));
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        endOfYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

        double t = endOfYear.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("0:ss", Locale.US).format(t);
```

This outputs of course only the seconds counting down which I'm trying to do in swift.

UPDATE:

All I have is:

```
func timer() {
    let time = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle)
    timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
}
```

And this just the entire time which I don't want...

Comment: Given that this is not a code-refactoring site, it would be great if you could add your `swift` code so that we can figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: There's the update

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time, but this is what I was looking for:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second, .Nanosecond], fromDate: date)
    let now = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: components.year, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute, second: components.second, nanosecond: components.nanosecond)!
    let newYears = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: components.year, month: 12, day: 31, hour: 01, minute: 00, second: 00, nanosecond: 00)!


    let units: NSCalendarUnit = [.Day, .Month, .Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
    let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(units, fromDate: now, toDate: newYears, options: [])

    let seconds = difference.second
```

This shows as a timer kind of format, similar to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/counters/newyear.html) where it says It is n days, n hours, n minutes, n seconds.
 Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You create 2 instances of `NSDate` and then you use `CFDateGetIntervalSinceDate(current_time, year_end)`

This is something similar to what you want (not very accurate, but search the documentation on how to get the exact year's end date including hours and seconds):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
let currentTime = NSDate()
let yearEnd = dateFormatter.dateFromString("31-12-2016")
let interval = CFDateGetTimeIntervalSinceDate(currentTime, yearEnd)
print("\(Int(interval)) seconds left until the year's end")
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the year programmically instead of harcoding it like the example code I wrote?

Comment: My example used a primitive method. I'm pretty sure you can get the year's end automatically. Check the **NSDate** and **NSCalendar** documentations.